# GNU Make conditional on two vars

Tags: gnu-make

I have two variables that look the same, yet, my gnu make comparison does not work as expected.

Here is a minimal experiment:

Makefile

```
test:
    $(eval $@_VER := $(shell aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions \
    --application-name $(APP_NAME) \
    --version-label $(NEW_VERSION) \
    --query "ApplicationVersions[*].VersionLabel" \
    --output=text))

    @echo $($@_VER)
    @echo $(NEW_VERSION)

ifeq ($(NEW_VERSION), $($@_VER))
    $(warning Version $($@_VER) already exists, skipping creating a new version.)
endif
```

and the output:

```
$ make test
7aeaec70b9a2820fde0f3b88ea40c4557b1ad42a
7aeaec70b9a2820fde0f3b88ea40c4557b1ad42a
```

You can see both vars look the same, but I expect warning message in the output. I have also tried removing whit space such as `$(strip $($@_VER)))`

Q:  What do I need to do make the conditional work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ifeq` is not part of the recipe where `$@` is defined, but a new top-level production.  Thus `$@` no longer resolves to the target name.

What you seem to want is a simple shell comparison, anyway.

```
:
@echo $($@_VER)
@echo $(NEW_VERSION)
if [ "$(NEW_VERSION)" = "$($@_VER)" ]; then \
    echo "Version $($@_VER) already exists, skipping" >&2; \
    false; fi
```